# How get value of a dynamically created HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The Ajax request returns HTML code with select list `id="country"`

Ar the main Js file there is event click where i try get value my dinamic created select list and get alert : *undefined*

```
var country = $('#country option:selected').val();
```

How could be get value?

Comment: *dynamic. You'll have to show us said HTML and how it's built -- we can't magically know your back end workings

Comment: I think you are no adding the returned html to the DOM. you have to do somthing like this: `$("#placeholder").html(htmlResult);` which the `placeholder` is an element already in your page.

Comment: You could try setting an id attribute to the created items with an auto incremented number.

Comment: I meant that the HTML code has not been loaded with the entire page and fetch and was returned via ajax

Comment: If you're loading this via Ajax, you will have to use the callback function to fetch the updated DOM elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the event is bound before the AJAX finishes then `$('#country option:selected')` won't find the element because at the time of binding the element does not yet exist. If you look for it within the `body` tag though, using `.find` that should solve your issue:

```
$('body').find('#country').find('option:selected').val()
```

Also, using `#country option:selected` will result in the browser first looking for all selected options and then looking for that within `#country`. So using `(#country).find('option:selected')` is generally faster, as it finds `#country` first.

Hope that's the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are not adding this 'select' list to the webpage, do this:

```
... // inside the event click handler, do this:

$.ajax("[*some url goes here*]")
.done(function(response){    // response will look like "<select id='country'> ... </select>"

    // Dynamically create a select element in memory
    var select = $(response);

    // Find the selected option in the select
    var chosenOption = $(select).find('option:selected');

    var value = null;

    // Null check, incase no option was checked and the chosenOption variable is null
    if (chosenOption != null) {
        value = $(chosenOption).val();
    }

});

...
```